# Polars: taking elements using two list columns

Tags: python-polars

Given a dataframe with two list columns I'd like to be able to create another column equivalent to using numpy.take.

For example, given a dataframe like:

```
In [58]: df = pl.DataFrame({"0": [[1,0], [0, 1]], "1": [[55, 101], [3, 9]]})

In [59]: df
Out[59]: 
shape: (2, 2)
┌───────────┬───────────┐
│ 0         ┆ 1         │
│ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ [1, 0]    ┆ [55, 101] │
│ [0, 1]    ┆ [3, 9]    │
└───────────┴───────────┘
```

I'd like to get a result like:

```
n [61]: pl.DataFrame({"0": [[1,0], [0, 1]], "1": [[55, 101], [3, 9]], "wanted": [[101, 55], [3, 9]]})
Out[61]: 
shape: (2, 3)
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ 0         ┆ 1         ┆ wanted    │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ [1, 0]    ┆ [55, 101] ┆ [101, 55] │
│ [0, 1]    ┆ [3, 9]    ┆ [3, 9]    │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

I can't use `..arr.eval(pl.element().take(??)` because we can't used name columns within `arr.eval()`. Obviously there are solutions using apply, but that kills performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close with your original solution. `arr.take`'s argument can also a `pl.Expr` that equates to an index or list of indices:

```py
df.with_columns(wanted=pl.col('1').arr.take(pl.col('0')))

shape: (2, 3)
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ 0         ┆ 1         ┆ wanted    │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ [1, 0]    ┆ [55, 101] ┆ [101, 55] │
│ [0, 1]    ┆ [3, 9]    ┆ [3, 9]    │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```